# Qt making a qmainwindow with videowidget inside displaying an image

Tags: qt, video, window, phonon

I am writing an application using `<Phonon/VideoWidget>`.

I'd like to have two windows.  One is the main window with controls for the video
And the other has the video itself. It will be displayed in another monitor. -fullscreen or not.

How can I make the video window - that can be moved or resizabled - with the video inside?

When not playing any video, the video window should display an image.

Comment: Have you compiled the video widget sample?  Are you asking how to merely implement the same thing with the controls in a separate window from the video?  http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/multimedia-videowidget.html

Comment: No, I am using #include <Phonon/VideoWidget> this class came with my SDK

Comment: also im asking how to display an image inside it when not playing videos

Comment: I don't know much about Phonon; my impression is that it's an abandoned older API.  But as for the ability to have a slot in a layout which swaps in one widget for another easily, look at QStackedWidget.  It would let you contain a QImage and a video player and swap between them.  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html

Comment: thanks. I didnt knew about QStackWidget, think it should do the job. I will try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I didnt use QStackedWidget, I extended Phonon::VideoWidget and made this class...

Heres the cpp:

```
MyVideoWidget::MyVideoWidget(QWidget *parent) : Phonon::VideoWidget(parent)
{
    label = new QLabel(this);
    label->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    label->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Light);
    label->setScaledContents(true);
}

void MyVideoWidget::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    if(!this->isFullScreen())
        this->enterFullScreen();
    else
        this->setFullScreen(false);
}

void MyVideoWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event)
{
    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Escape)
    {
        if(!this->isFullScreen())
            this->enterFullScreen();
        else
            this->setFullScreen(false);
    }
}

void MyVideoWidget::enterImageMode(QString imagePath)
{
    QPixmap pmap;
    pmap.fill(QColor(255, 255, 255));
    if(!pmap.load(imagePath))
    {
        label->setText("Erro ao carregar imagem: "+imagePath);
        if(!label->isVisible())
                label->show();
        return;
    }
    label->setPixmap(pmap);
    if(!label->isVisible())
        label->show();
    repaint();
}

void MyVideoWidget::enterVideoMode()
{
    label->hide();
}

void MyVideoWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
{
    Phonon::VideoWidget::resizeEvent(event);
    label->setGeometry(this->geometry());
    repaint();
}

MyVideoWidget::~MyVideoWidget() 
{

}
```